# Is there a way to make an android device simulate a USB keyboard to a PC?

Tags: android, keyboard, usb

I don't know if this already exists or is possible, but I want to make it so I can make my android devices control a game on the PC via keystrokes.

For example, let's say I have an app with 2 buttons, STOP and GO.  When I press GO on my android device, the computer thinks that I pressed G on the keyboard and the PC game does what is assigned to G.  Same thing with STOP but with a different key assignment.  Is something like this possible/already exist?

It doesn't matter to me what the connection to the PC is.

Answer (score -1):

For this you are going to need a server on PC which will then simulate your keys according to the data sent from Android device. So on your Android you have a client and on the PC you will have server. You will need to make two apps for this. If this is just for fun. Try looking on GooglePlay to see whether there are any already done solutions. You have for mouse, that I tried.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.